# Classic ASP with MS Access DELETE fails in loop

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have a simple loop where I extract two values from a csv string multiple times.

I then send the values to a DELETE routine. Like so:

```
cvsString = "aaa_bbb, ccc_ddd"
arrCvs = split( cvsString, ",")
for each pair in arrCvs
    valArray  = split(pair, "_")
    Call DeleteRow (valArray(0), valArray(1))
next

sub DeleteRow(col1Val, col2Val)
    sql = "DELETE * FROM tblName WHERE col1 = 'col1Val' AND col2 = 'col2Val'"
    dbh.Execute sql, rowsAffected
end sub
```

Apologies, I can't copy my code so you get psuedo-code and a few shortcuts. The code works .... except

The first request to DELETE succeeds but all others fail. rowAffected returns:
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, etc

Any ideas. I searched where I can with no results

Comment: are you absolutely sure the data exists in the database after the first delete?

Comment: Are you concatenating passed in variables, *co1val1* and *colw2val*, or using string literals to the delete statement?

Comment: A CSV file is an abbreviation on [Comma-separated **values**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Should't you  first split the data to rows, then split each row to values?

Comment: Could it be a DB-locking issue? I once had such an issue when trying to run massive number of DELETE orders. please [read about it here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=282271).

Answer (score 0):

Have the loop create one SQL, and execute it:

```
cvsString = "aaa_bbb, ccc_ddd"
arrCvs = split( cvsString, ",")
SQL = "DELETE * FROM tblName WHERE"
for each pair in arrCvs    
    valArray  = split(pair, "_")
    Vals = Vals & " or (col1 = '" & valArray(0) & "' AND col2 = '" & valArray(1) & "')"
next
dbh.Execute sql & Right(Vals, Len(Vals)-len(" or")) , rowsAffected
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you put static value instead of adding the actual, dynamic, value of the variables you pass to the sub routine.

Proper way would be using parameters:

```
Set cmd = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = dbh
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM tblName WHERE col1=? AND col2=?"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("col1Val", 202, 1, 255, col1Val))//adVarWChar
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("col2Val", 202, 1, 255, col2Val))//adVarWChar
cmd.Execute rowsAffected
```